in play console google playcore version issue it needs api 34 to target
enter image description here
i have find build.gridl file and update the playcore 1.10.3 but and rebuild the game and again similar problem how to fix this using android studio
my target api is 34
i just want to publish the game and tried to to update google core in unity project build.gridle
i want to update my unity game google android playcore version to an android 14 compatible version
my target apk version is 34
